# JDO support for "like" operator

Tags: jdo

I am learning JDO. I am using it with an sql database. I see no example talking about the common sql "like" operator.
It seems there is no "like operator for compatibility with non sql databases.
I need it. How can I do with JDO?

I add that I am using Datanucleus version 4 as JDO implementation because I am using Apache Isis. It seems that "matches" is implemented only in version 5.

Comment: Try regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDOQL supports methods on objects, and follows Java syntax. Consequently it supports `String.matches`, providing regular expression matching. See the JDO spec and [this link in the DataNucleus docs](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jdo/query.html#jdoql_methods)

Comment: Your reply is correct. I see now that I am using DataNucleus 4 and, infact, there is no "matches" method. Version 4 docs are so different from version 5 that it seems another product.

Comment: "matches" is implemented in EVERY version of DataNucleus, and was in JPOX its predecessor. It's in the JDO SPEC so any compliant implementation has to provide it

Comment: It's also in the documentation for v4.1 http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_4_1/jdo/jdoql.html#methods

Answer (score 1):

With datanucleus resolved by Isis 1.15 (core 4.1.1, jdo-query 4.0.5, and so on) I can use "matches" inside a query defined as a string. But I cannot use it in a TypesafeQuery, the StringExpression has no method called "matches".